# iOS calling a method when user touches a certain area

Tags: ios, methods, uiview, touch

So i have this space between between keyboard and an object. And i want to trigger a method when the user touches in this certain area. How would i go about doing this? 
I've tried using a UIView with a UITapGesture but cant seem to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

What is the "object" that you are referencing?

If it's already enabled for user interaction then all you need is...

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // do something
}
```

Put this in the view controller. The keyboard will consume touches so this won't fire. If the "object" has user interaction enabled it will consume the touch also. This only fires when pressing an area that doesn't consume touches.

If it doesn't consume touches then...

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // get the touch
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    // get the location of the touch in the main view of the view controller
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    // if the touch is inside the object then ignore it
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(object.frame, touchPoint)) {
        return;
    }

    // this is where you do something.
}
```

Comment: the object is a UITextField in a custom TableViewCell. If you can imagine a Cell at the top and the keyboard, theres space in between. When i click in that space, it selects another cell which causes graphical glitches and bugs. So I'm looking to eliminate that problem all together.

Answer (score 0):

You might use an invisible button:

```
UIButton *theButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(functionYouWantToCall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
theButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
[self.view addSubview:theButton];
```

Set the frame according to your needs. When you are done with the button, use `[theButton removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: Seems like it might work. The thing is, I'm not familiar with CGRectMake's parameters. I know (0,0) is position in the top left corner of the iOS screen. But the width and height...a grey area for me. So the width, is it +/- the the coordinate/origin? Or is it just one way?

Comment: The x and y mark the origin of the rectangle, which is the top left corner. The width and height are measured from that origin point; they are always positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

Add a UITapGesture to self.view but make sure you set the property for cancelsTouchInView to NO. This will prevent you from overiding any touch methods you have already placed on screen.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(someAction)];
tapGesture.cancelsTouchInView = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add additional keys to your keyboard, like how Chrome has shortcuts to ".com" and such, you might want to try:

```
[self.yourTextView setInputAccessoryView:toolBar];
```